# How to select table in the order multiple case

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a stored procedure to select rows from a table with the order depending on the input variable. I tried this code:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[advance_search] (
    @keyword nvarchar(50),
    @casi nvarchar(50),
    @loai nvarchar(5),
    @order nchar(10)
)
as
   select *
   from Nhac n 
   inner join CaSi cs on n.MaCS = cs.MaCS 
   where TenBH like '%'+@keyword+'%' AND TenCS like '%'+@casi+'%'
   ORDER BY 
      CASE 
          WHEN @loai = 'Ngayramat' AND @order = 'DESC' THEN n.Ngayramat 
          ELSE NULL 
      END DESC,
      CASE 
          WHEN @loai = 'Ngayramat' AND @order = 'ASC' THEN n.Ngayramat 
          ELSE NULL 
      END ASC,
      CASE 
          WHEN @loai = 'TenBH' AND @order = 'DESC' THEN n.TenBH 
          ELSE NULL 
      END DESC,
      CASE 
          WHEN @loai = 'TenBH' AND @order = 'ASC' THEN n.TenBH 
          ELSE NULL 
      END ASC,
      CASE 
          WHEN @loai = 'Luotnghe' AND @order = 'DESC' THEN n.Luotnghe 
          ELSE NULL 
      END DESC,
      CASE 
          WHEN @loai = 'Luotnghe' AND @order = 'ASC' THEN n.Luotnghe 
          ELSE NULL 
      END ASC
```

I want to select all from 2 tables `Casi` and `Nhac` with the order depend on input variable.

For example: if the input variable :

```
@loai = 'luotnghe', @order = 'DESC'
```

the command will be :

```
select *
from Nhac n inner join CaSi cs on n.MaCS = cs.MaCS 
where TenBH like '%'+@keyword+'%' AND TenCS like '%'+@casi+'%'
ORDER BY n.luotnghe DESC
```

Any help would be great

Comment: What happens when you try your query outside a stored procedure? Does it get parsed properly? Does it produce the expected results, but the order is not what you expect?

Comment: Your query looks like it is doing what you want.  What is the problem?

Comment: @GordonLinoff It doesn't sort as I want. As the example, it returned the result without sorted by n.luotnghe

Comment: @AnhNguyen . . . perhaps your database has a case sensitive collation.  Try passing in `'Luotnghe'`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff when i pass 'TenBH'(nvarchar) it worked but when the input is luotnghe(bigint), I didn't sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is simple.  Your variable declaration is too short:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[advance_search] (
    @keyword nvarchar(50),
    @casi nvarchar(50),
    @loai nvarchar(5),
-------------------^
    @order nchar(10)
)
```

And, you are then comparing `@loai` to an 8-character value, so they can never be equal.

Change it to some larger value:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[advance_search] (
    @keyword nvarchar(255),
    @casi nvarchar(255),
    @loai nvarchar(255),
-------------------^
    @order nchar(10)
)
```

For some irrational reason, I often use `255` as a "larger" value for string lengths.